# Compare string with words changing positions

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I must compare a lof of string and i have the problems
many words are at different positions

for example

> Economie - Un oeil sur les medias

or

> Un oeil sur les medias - Economie

Is there some algorithm that verifies the percentage of matching the repetition control over individual words?

Answer (score 1):

The [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) is a natural, similarity measure for this use case.  Here's an implementation that takes term frequencies into account, such that the document "a a a a" is not the same as "a":

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class JaccardWordWiseSimilarityDemo {

    protected Map<String, Integer> termFrequencies(final String document) {
        if (document.isEmpty()) {
            return new HashMap<>(0);
        }

        final Map<String, Integer> termFrequencies = new HashMap<>();
        final Scanner terms = new Scanner(document);

        while (terms.hasNext()) {
            final String term = terms.next();
            final int termFrequency = termFrequencies.containsKey(term)
                ? 1 + termFrequencies.get(term)
                : 1;
            termFrequencies.put(term, termFrequency);
        }

        return termFrequencies;
    }

    protected int intersectionSize(
            final Map<String, Integer> lhsTermFrequencies,
            final Map<String, Integer> rhsTermFrequencies) {
        final Set<String> lhsTerms = lhsTermFrequencies.keySet();
        final Set<String> rhsTerms = rhsTermFrequencies.keySet();
        final Set<String> intersectionTerms = new HashSet<>(lhsTerms);
        intersectionTerms.retainAll(rhsTerms);
        int intersectionSize = 0;
        for (final String pair : intersectionTerms) {
            intersectionSize += Math.min(
                lhsTermFrequencies.get(pair),
                rhsTermFrequencies.get(pair));
        }
        return intersectionSize;
    }

      protected int unionSize(
            final Map<String, Integer> lhsTermFrequencies,
            final Map<String, Integer> rhsTermFrequencies) {
        final Set<String> lhsTerms = lhsTermFrequencies.keySet();
        final Set<String> rhsTerms = rhsTermFrequencies.keySet();
        final Set<String> unionTerms = new HashSet<>(lhsTerms);
        unionTerms.addAll(rhsTerms);
        int unionSize = 0;
        for (final String term : unionTerms) {
            if (lhsTermFrequencies.containsKey(term)
                    && rhsTermFrequencies.containsKey(term)) {
                unionSize += Math.max(
                    lhsTermFrequencies.get(term),
                    rhsTermFrequencies.get(term));
            }
            else if (lhsTermFrequencies.containsKey(term)) {
                unionSize += lhsTermFrequencies.get(term);
            }
            else {
                unionSize += rhsTermFrequencies.get(term);
            }
        }
        return unionSize;
    }

    protected double between(final String lhsDocument, final String rhsDocument) {
        if (lhsDocument.equals(rhsDocument)) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        if (lhsDocument.isEmpty() || rhsDocument.isEmpty()) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        final Map<String, Integer> lhsTermFrequencies = termFrequencies(lhsDocument);
        final Map<String, Integer> rhsTermFrequencies = termFrequencies(rhsDocument);
        return (double) intersectionSize(lhsTermFrequencies, rhsTermFrequencies)
             / (double) unionSize(lhsTermFrequencies, rhsTermFrequencies);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final JaccardWordWiseSimilarityDemo similarity =
            new JaccardWordWiseSimilarityDemo();
        for (int lhsIndex = 0; lhsIndex < args.length; lhsIndex += 1) {
            final String lhsDocument = args[lhsIndex];
            for (int rhsIndex = 0; rhsIndex < args.length; rhsIndex += 1) {
                if (lhsIndex != rhsIndex) {
                    final String rhsDocument = args[rhsIndex];
                    System.out.printf("similarity(\"%s\", \"%s\") = %.7f %%%n",
                        lhsDocument, rhsDocument,
                        100.0 * similarity.between(lhsDocument, rhsDocument));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample runs:

```
% java JaccardWordWiseSimilarityDemo "Economie - Un oeil sur les medias" "Un oeil sur les medias - Economie"
similarity("Economie - Un oeil sur les medias", "Un oeil sur les medias - Economie") = 100.0000000 %
similarity("Un oeil sur les medias - Economie", "Economie - Un oeil sur les medias") = 100.0000000 %

% java JaccardWordWiseSimilarityDemo "a a a a" "a"
similarity("a a a a", "a") = 25.0000000 %
similarity("a", "a a a a") = 25.0000000 %
```

If term casing is not important then you should lowercase every document before computing their similarities.

Note that this example does not tokenize punctuation correctly, as it merely splits on whitespace.  If you need to support punctuation tokenization then I would suggest looking into the [Stanford CoreNLP tokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to split the string on whitespace, and compute the intersection of the resulting sets of words:

```
static double IntersectionSize(string a, string b) {
    var wordsA = a.Split(null);
    var wordsB = b.Split(null);
    if (wordsA.Length == 0 || wordsB.Length == 0) {
        // Avoid division by zero on return
        return 0;
    }
    var common = wordsA.Intersect(wordsB);
    double res = common.Sum(w => w.Length); // Total length of common words
    return 2 * res / (wordsA.Distinct().Sum(w => w.Length) + wordsB.Distinct().Sum(w => w.Length));
}
```

This produces a fraction of total length of common words to the average of total lengths of words in both strings.

Note that the above algorithm does not care how many times a word is present in a string. For example, `"a a a"` and `"a"` will return 100% match.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Omz8gd)

Comment: Some words (like articles `a`, `the`) can well appear many times in the same string; `Intersect` can bring *bios* in that case

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That's a fair observation, I added a note to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

The [Longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) is usually calculated on per-character basis, but if you split words and probably apply some intelligent [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), it could also work on word level.

Answer (score 0):

try this. Hope it helps.

```
    string s1 = "word1 - word2";
    string s2 = "word2 - word1";

    var s1words = new HashSet<string>(s1.Split(' ').Distinct());
    var s2words = new HashSet<string>(s2.Split(' ').Distinct());

    // number of s1 words which contains in s2
    var s1INs2 = s1words.Count(x => s2words.Contains(x));

    // number of s2 words which contains in s1
    var s2INs1 = s2words.Count(x => s1words.Contains(x));
```